# Problem with fetching data from mysql into email

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to send data from mysql into email :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) 
{
    // append data of each row to $msg.
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    {
        $body .= " <style>
        table{width:100%}
            table, th, td {
                border: 1px solid black;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
            th, td {
                padding: 5px;
                text-align: left;
            }
        </style> ". 
        "<table>".
        "<tr> <th> name </th>
              <th>last name</th>
              <th>email</th>
        </tr>".

        "<tr>".
            "<td>". $row["col1"]. "</td>".
            "<td>" . $row["col2"]. "</td>".
            "<td>" . $row["col3"]. "</td>".
        "</tr>". 
    "</table>" ;      
  }

  $body = wordwrap($body,70);
  mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
} 
else 
{
  echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

It works fine but the only problem that I'm getting multi tables but I want to display all the rows in single table.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the table HTML tags outside of your loop:

```
<table>
    <thead>
      <th>Header</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php //put your loop here ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign HTML table tag to body variable outside for loop.

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM orders ORDER BY id";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {

    $body= " <style>
    table{width:100%}
    table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    }
    th, td {
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: left;
    }
    </style> <table>";
   $body.="<tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>last name</th>
      <th>email</th>
     </tr>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $body.=
      "<tr>".
        "<td>". $row["col1"]. "</td>".
        "<td>" . $row["col2"]. "</td>".
        "<td>" . $row["col3"]. "</td>" .
      "</tr>";
      }
    $body.="</table>" ;
      $body = wordwrap($body,70);
      mail($to_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    } else {
      echo "0 results";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
```

Comment: You've made a mistake in `while` loop.

Comment: yes there is a mistake in this code but thank you anyway :)

Comment: Yes, I just Updated my Answer. Thanks

Comment: This is a very poor answer. Instead of just posting code with `Use this instead` you should explain why this would solve the OP's problem.

Comment: I just added the explanation. hope that will help future readers.

Comment: I think that explanation belongs to another answer / question :-)